# Call class method in another class method

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

In Python 3, how can I call an inherited method in another class method?

```
class A:
    name = 'foo'

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name


class B(A):

    @classmethod
    def do_other(cls):
        cls.get_name()
```

in the cls.get_name() it complains that 'Parameter "self" unfilled'.
How can I overcome this without having to change the do_other to a regular method?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by creating a temporary instance.
This is one way.

```
 class A:
    name = 'foo'
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = A.name
    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name


class B(A):

    @classmethod
    def do_other(cls):
        return B.get_name(cls)


print(B.do_other())
```

This is the second way

```
class B(A):

@classmethod
def do_other(cls):
    return A().get_name()
```

Here you can also replace A() with B() since class B is inheriting from class A

Answer (score 1):

You acutally only have to return the `cls.get_name(cls)`

```
class A:
    name = 'foo'
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name


class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def do_other(cls):
        return cls.get_name(cls)


print(B.do_other())
```